# c# LINQ Faster solution needed. Querying large lists of objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am looking for a faster solution to the following problem.

I have three lists of products available in three different stores. I want to create a unique list containing all products available in the three stores and a unique list of products that appear in more than one store.

```cs
class Product{
    public int Id;
    // 
    public Product(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }
}
List<Product> store1 = new List<Product>();
List<Product> store2 = new List<Product>();
List<Product> store3 = new List<Product>();
List<Product> allUniqueProducts = new List<Product>();
List<Product> moreThanOneStore= new List<Product>();
```

Fill the lists with some arbitrary values

```cs
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
    store1.Add(new Product(i));
    store2.Add(new Product(i+2000));
    store3.Add(new Product(i+5000));
}
```

This is my solution however when the lists are large (in the region of 10,000) this code runs pretty slowly.

```cs
processStoreList(store1);
processStoreList(store2);
processStoreList(store3);

void processStoreList( List<Product> storeList ){

    foreach ( Product pd in storeList ){

        if ( !( allUniqueProducts.Count( x => x.Id == pd.Id ) > 0 ))
            allUniqueProducts.Add(pd);

        else if ( !( moreThanOneStore.Count( x => x.Id == pd.Id ) > 0 ))
            moreThanOneStore.Add(pd);
     }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a `Dictionary<int, Product>` instead of `List<Product>`.

This way, `ContainsKey` will be O(1) instead of O(n)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead of List.  The **IEqualityComparer** is needed to ensure that two **Product** with the same **id** are considered the same.

```
        public class ProductEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
        {
            public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
            {
                return x.Id == y.Id;
            }

            public int GetHashCode(Product obj)
            {
               return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            HashSet<Product> allUniqueProducts = 
                new HashSet<Product>(new ProductEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: @SLaks what about GetHashCode ??

Answer (score 1):

You can add all items to a [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx). The [HashSet<T>.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx) returns `false` if the item is already present, which allows you to detect if an item appears more than once. You need an [IEqualityComparer<Product>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) that compares products by `Id`.

```
var allUniqueProducts = new HashSet<Product>(byIdComparer);
var moreThanOneStore = new HashSet<Product>(byIdComparer);

foreach (var product in store1.Concat(store2).Concat(store3))
{
    if (!allUniqueProducts.Add(product))
    {
        moreThanOneStore.Add(product);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` is so .net 2.0 - instead use Linq.

`Enumerable.GroupBy` uses a hashed collection to perform the grouping.

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Product>> groups = store1
   .Concat(store2)
   .Concat(store3)
   .GroupBy(prod => prod.Id);

List<Product> allProducts = groups
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();

List<Product> moreThanOneStoreProducts = groups
  .Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any())
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();
```

If you want to (later) use those id's to find groups in the list of groups, use `Enumerable.ToLookup` instead of `Enumerable.GroupBy`.

```
ILookup<int, Product>> lookup = store1
   .Concat(store2)
   .Concat(store3)
   .ToLookup(prod => prod.Id)

List<Product> someGroup = lookup[3].ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the `Count()` method on your lists, you are causing it to loop through all of the items in the collection. This is very time consuming. Using a `Dictionary<TKey,TItem>` will use the keys for lookup which is much faster.

```
void Run3() {
  var stores = new List<List<Product>>() { store1, store2, store3 };
  var all = new Dictionary<int, Product>();
  var multi = new Dictionary<int, Product>();
  foreach (var store in stores) {
    foreach(var product in store) {
      if (all.ContainsKey(product.Id))
        multi[product.Id] = product;
      else
        all[product.Id] = product;
    }
  }
}
```